# SQL Dump Import Error Causes and Solutions

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, sqlyog

i'm having difficulty importing my back-up sql file on sqlyog, i dont know what the cause is but probably it's the size of .sql because i'm trying to import 1.58GB of .sql file, what do you think is the best solution to import my .sql to my mysql database? thanks in advance!

[image: SQLYog error message screenshot]

Comment: it seems you have a lot of errors. try open the .err file with a better text editor and find out the problem or post few lines here.

Comment: Paste the error here...

Answer (score 0):

Error log file is too large that's why notepad is not responding. you should clean your error log and then re-import so that you can check error logs.
Error may be due to max_allowed_packet or table / database already exists etc etc..